# Link To Specific Option Values

Tags: php, jquery, hyperlink

I am trying to modify some code I found on this site (courtesy of mqchen) to enable linking to specific option values. Although it's close to what I'm looking for, I have little php knowledge and therefore need some help. Here's the original code:

```
<?php
$options = array('Norway', 'United States', 'Springfield');
echo '<select>';
foreach($options as $country) {
    if(array_key_exists('selected', $_GET) && $_GET['selected'] === $country) {
        echo '<option selected="selected">'.$country.'</option>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<option>'.$country.'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

And the link would be something like:

```
/countries.html?country=norway
```

I need to have not only the country between the option tags, but also a value in the option tag, so that the final output would be:

```
<option value="unitedstates">United States</option>
```

I was also going to edit the third line to:

```
echo '<select name="name" size="1" onchange="ShowHide(this.value);">';
```

because my select tag currently has those attributes for certain functionality. So basically all I need to do, I believe, is add another array containing the option values that line up with the countries and put the variable into the option tag, which I assumed would be:

```
<option value="'.$valueid.'">
```

But I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$options = array('norway' =>'Norway', 'unitedstates' => 'United States', 'springfield' => 'Springfield');
echo '<select name="name" size="1" onchange="ShowHide(this.value);">';
foreach($options as $key => $country) {
    if(array_key_exists('selected', $_GET) && $_GET['selected'] === $country) {
        echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$key.' >'.$country.'</option>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<option value="'.$key.'>'.$country.'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

BTW - this is php not jQuery

Comment: Thanks, Nicola. I noticed that I put jquery instead of php and was just about to edit it when I saw your answer. It's not working because I think I have too much going on in the query string. I'm linking to two separate spry tabbed panels before selecting the option value. So my actual links are like this: `www.mysite.com/registration.html?type=tennis&program=juniors&country=unitedstates` The result is that it always goes straight to the first option regardless of the link.

Comment: I tested the code with just the country query, and it still didn't link to the selected value. The selected="selected" just isn't executing.

Comment: @Beau can you post an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: I'd like to, but it's not rendering the php (this is my first time trying it).

Comment: @Beau yes because you can't render php there, i just wanted to see the html output. Have you tried adding `echo '<select name="name" size="1" onchange="ShowHide(this.value);">'; ` on the third row

Comment: moving that line did not work (it created separate drop downs for each value). The html output is exactly as it should be, except the selected attribute is not appearing.

Comment: Solution: Had to change the fifth line in Nicola's answer to: `if(array_key_exists('country', $_GET) && $_GET['country'] === $country) {`